# @font-face not working in mobile (specifically Android)

Tags: android, css, mobile, fonts, font-face

I have totally tried everything and researched online for at least an hour, would really appreciate the help.

I have the following code for my font. It's showing fine on desktop but not on mobile:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    src: url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.eot'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.svg#HelveticaNeue') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    src: url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.eot'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.svg#HelveticaNeue-Medium') format('svg');
         font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    src: url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.eot'),
         url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.svg#HelveticaNeue-Bold') format('svg');
         font-weight: bold;
}
```

is there something that i am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your font-face url("https://fosoa.ie/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff2") is forbidden error! Check permission your path.